# Group array of objects into 2D arrays based on nested value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects like this

```
array1 = [{data: ..., name: a}, {data: ..., name: b}, {data: ..., name: a}, {data: ..., name: c}, {data: ..., name: c}, {data: ..., name: b}]
```

I want to sort it in such a way that it groups them by name in sub-arrays

```
array2 = [
  [{data: ..., name: a}, {data: ..., name: a}, {data: ..., name: a}],
  [{data: ..., name: b}, {data: ..., name: b}],
  [{data: ..., name: c}]
]
```

I don't always know what the name will be, so I can not manually do 'if name === 'a' etc.

Comment: What have you tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Array.reduce()` here to group your data by `name`. We create an object with a property for each name present, appending any matching value to an array at this value.
We'd then used `Object.values()` to create our desired array.

```js
array1 = [{data: {}, name: 'a' }, {data: {}, name: 'b'}, {data: {}, name: 'a'}, {data: {}, name: 'c'}, {data: {}, name: 'c'}, {data: {}, name: 'b'}];

const grouped = Object.values(array1.reduce((acc, cur) => { 
    acc[cur.name] = [...(acc[cur.name] || []), cur];
    return acc;
}, {}));

console.log('Grouped:', grouped);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually this is `grouping` not sorting.

This can be done with a looping technique. I use `Array.reduce` here

```js
const array1 = [{ data: 'some value', name: 'a' }, { data: 'some value', name: 'b' }, { data: 'some value', name: 'a' }, { data: 'some value', name: 'c' }, { data: 'some value', name: 'c' }, { data: 'some value', name: 'b' }];
const array2 = array1.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const node = acc.find(item => item.find(subItem => subItem.name === curr.name));
  if(node) {
    node.push(curr)
  } else {
    acc.push([curr])
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(array2);
```

Comment: Can you explain how the variables `node` is being added to the accumulator? It looks like its being defined and updated, but it isnt being returned. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code

```js
let objMap = {};
array1.map(arr=>{
 if(!objMap[arr.name]){
  objMap[arr.name]=[]
 }
 objMap[arr.name].push(arr)
})
console.log(Object.values(objMap));
```

Comment: Don't use map if you're going to disregard the returned array. use `forEach` or a loop.

Answer (score 0):

It can be solved just by adding some object map.

```js
array1 = [{data: {}, name: 'a'},{data: {}, name: 'a'}, {data: {}, name: 'b'}, {data: {}, name: 'a'}, {data: {}, name: 'c'}, {data: {}, name: 'c'}, {data: {}, name: 'c'}, {data: {}, name: 'b'},{data: {}, name: 'c'}];

newObject = {};

array1.forEach((object)=>{
  if((!newObject[object.name])){
    newObject[object.name] = [object];  
  } else {
    newObject[object.name].push(object);
  }
});

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```
array2 = Object.values(newObject);

console.log(array2);
```